# Add user input to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am brand new to coding. Im having issues adding input to the end of my array

```
function my_array_add(arr, value){
   arr.push (value);
}
console.log (my_array_add(arr, 9));
```

I just keep getting undefined. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Return `arr` inside function

Comment: You must `return arr;`. Functions without an explicit return always implicitly return `undefined`.

Comment: Return fixed it! Im still getting used to all of this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value from your function otherwise it will return `undefined`:

```js
let arr = [];

function my_array_add(arr, value){
   arr.push (value);
   return arr;
}
console.log (my_array_add(arr, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an input to the end of an array, you can simplify the operation without writing an extra function. .push is the function you need to accomplish the desired outcome.

```
let arr = []; // first initialize an empty array

arr.push(input_1); // assume input_1 = 1, it can be anything in general
arr.push(input_2); // assume input_2 = 2

console.log(array); // output : [1,2]
```